# SQL - use regex to search for column value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

```
CREATE TABLE myTable1
(
    ua  text,
    platform text
);

INSERT INTO myTable1
    ("ua", "platform")
VALUES ('name:Safari,version:16.2', 'desktop'),
       ('name:Safari,version:15.2', 'desktop'),
       ('name:Firefox,version:105.0', 'desktop'),
       ('name:Chrome,version:100.0.4798.88', 'desktop'),
       ('name:Chrome,version:100.0.7898.70', 'desktop'),
       ('name:Chrome,version:99.0.6723.59', 'desktop')
  ;
```

| ua | platform |
| --- | --- |
| name:Safari,version:16.2 | desktop |
| name:Safari,version:15.2 | desktop |
| name:Firefox,version:105.0 | desktop |
| name:Chrome,version:100.0.4798.88 | desktop |
| name:Chrome,version:100.0.7898.70 | desktop |
| name:Chrome,version:99.0.6723.59 | desktop |

```
CREATE TABLE myTable2
(
    uaid  int,
    keyword      text,
    platform         text
);

INSERT INTO myTable2
    ("uaid", "keyword", "platform")
VALUES ('7014', '%Windows%Chrome/99.0%', 'Chrome'),
       ('7014', '%Maintosh%Chrome/99.0%', 'Chrome'),
       ('7014', '%X11%Chrome/99.0%', 'Chrome'),
       ('7068', '%Windows%Chrome/100.0%', 'Chrome'),
       ('7068', '%Maintosh%Chrome/100.0%', 'Chrome'),
       ('7026', '%Windows%Firefox/105.0%', 'Firefox'),
       ('7026', '%Macintosh%Firefox/105.0%', 'Firefox'),
       ('2015', '%Android%Firefox/105.0%', 'Firefox Mobile'),
       ('7030', '%(Macintosh;%) Version/16.2 Safari/%', 'Safari'),
       ('7030', '%(Macintosh;%) Version/16.2.1 Safari/%', 'Safari'),
       ('7036', '%(Macintosh;%) Version/15.2 Safari/%', 'Safari')
  ;
```

| uaid | keyword | platform |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7014 | %Windows%Chrome/99.0% | Chrome |
| 7014 | %Maintosh%Chrome/99.0% | Chrome |
| 7014 | %X11%Chrome/99.0% | Chrome |
| 7068 | %Windows%Chrome/100.0% | Chrome |
| 7068 | %Maintosh%Chrome/100.0% | Chrome |
| 7026 | %Windows%Firefox/105.0% | Firefox |
| 7026 | %Macintosh%Firefox/105.0% | Firefox |
| 2015 | %Android%Firefox/105.0% | Firefox Mobile |
| 7030 | %(Macintosh;%) Version/16.2 Safari/% | Safari |
| 7030 | %(Macintosh;%) Version/16.2.1 Safari/% | Safari |
| 7036 | %(Macintosh;%) Version/15.2 Safari/% | Safari |

The result I expect to get is:

| ua | platform | uaid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name:Safari,version:16.2 | desktop | 7030 |
| name:Safari,version:15.2 | desktop | 7036 |
| name:Firefox,version:105.0 | desktop | 7026 |
| name:Chrome,version:100.0.4798.88 | desktop | 7068 |
| name:Chrome,version:100.0.7898.70 | desktop | 7068 |
| name:Chrome,version:99.0.6723.59 | desktop | 7014 |

Now I have to use

```
select uaid from myTable2 where keyword like '%16.2%Safari%';
```

to look for uaid. Since the keyword pattern in lookup table myTable2 is different for each platform, is there an easier way to get uaid using regex in sql?
Thanks!

Comment: FYI, LIKE patterns are not regular expressions. The regexp would be `.*XXX.*`.

Comment: I don't see how your expected results come from the sample data. `name:Safari,version:16.2` doesn't match any of the patterns for uaid 7030, since it doesn't contain `(Macintosh;)`.

Comment: in myTable2, it has '%(Macintosh;%) Version/16.2 Safari/%'. it corresponds to uaid = 7030

Comment: But none of the `ua` strings have `(Macintosh;`. Do you think the `()` make it optional?

Comment: the insert code doesn't work with mysql. are you sure you have tagged it correctly

Comment: it doesn't have to 100% match. you can treat '(Macintosh)' or 'Windows' as optional. The platform name (chrome, firefox, safari, etc) and version (the numbers before first dot) has to match the keyword in myTable2.

Comment: i am using this interface. it's not mysql.  https://dbfiddle.uk/5auwPp2l

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN` with `LIKE` in the `ON` condition.

```
SELECT ua, myTable1.platform, uaid
FROM myTable1
JOIN myTable2 ON ua LIKE keyword
```

Comment: sorry, i don't think your query works in my case. at first, the 'ua' in myTable1 not even matches the pattern of 'keyword' in myTable2. how can you join them together?

Comment: It doesn't work because none of the patterns match your user agent strings.

Comment: that's why i am asking how to use regular expression to make 'ua' that could match 'keyword'

Comment: Figure out what patterns you're actually looking for, and write regular expressions that match them. If the UA strings have `:`, don't use `/` in your patterns.

Comment: Are you asking how to automatically convert those keywords into the corresponding patterns? That seems too complicated for SQL, it has very limited string processing functions.

Comment: i am thinking to separate 'ua' column value in myTable1 as separate columns, ex. 'name:Chrome,version:100.0.4798.88'. split this string to two columns: one 'platform_name' column = Chrome  another one 'version' column = 100. (keep the dot).